# How to handle default Angular form validation Error?

Tags: angular

I am using reactive form validation here. I have 3 fields Email, Full Name & Password (All are mandatory).
When I just click on any one of the fields and just click off the fields. By default, Angular shows red color border over the fields

I would like to show the red color border when I type in the fields and remove all the text and click outside.

I don't want to show red color border when I just click into the fields and click off the fields.

How to override this default behavior?

Template

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(signUpForm)" #f="ngForm" 
        #signUpForm="ngForm" [formGroup] = "signup"
        fxShow="true" fxFlex fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center stretch" fxLayoutGap="4px">

        <div>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Email</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="Enter the email" name="email" formControlName="email">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Full Name</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="Enter your fullname" name="fullname" formControlName="fullname">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="Enter the password" name="password" formControlName="password">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-info height_40" type="submit" [disabled]="signup.invalid" fxFlex="98">
                Sign Up
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Typescript file

```
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  signup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.signup = formBuilder.group({
        email: ['', Validators.required],
        fullname: ['', Validators.required],
        password: ['', Validators.required]
      })
   }
}
```

Comment: you want to highlight error only when you type?

Comment: yes. actually, when i do(text) something in the input and remove all the text, then i need to show red color border. if i just click on the input text field and click outside of it and shows red color border not required.!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the documnentation:

> By default, these error messages are shown when the control is invalid
> and either the user has interacted with (touched)

You can override behavior you can use custom [errorStateMatcher](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview).create custom MyErrorStateMatcher by extending ErrorStateMatcher interface. then place this error matcher on matInput element something like this:

**component.ts**

```
/** Error when control is pristine. */
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    console.log(control!.touched && control!.dirty); 
    return !control!.pristine;
  } 
} 
matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
```

**component.html**

```
<input type="email" matInput [formControl]="emailFormControl" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
           placeholder="Ex. pat@example.com">
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sqhvbz?file=src/app/./input-error-state-matcher-example.html)